# Syntax error in: __asm__ ("some_code":::"cc")

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I use C++ for project, there includes a c header file ira.h as below:

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

extern inline void disable_irqs() {
    __asm__ __volatile__("\torc  #0x80,ccr\n":::"cc");
}

extern inline void enable_irqs() {
    __asm__ __volatile__("\tandc #0x7f,ccr\n":::"cc");
}

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

When I compile it, I got error as below:

```
/usr/local/bin/h8300-hitachi-hms-g++ -DCXX -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -O2 -fno-builtin -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -I/brickos/include -I/brickos/include/lnp -I. -I/brickos/boot  -c rcx1.C -o rcx1.o
In file included from PowerFunctionsController.H:32,
             from rcx1.H:27,
             from rcx1.C:21:
/brickos/include/lnp/sys/irq.h: In function `void disable_irqs(...)':
/brickos/include/lnp/sys/irq.h:99: parse error before `::'
/brickos/include/lnp/sys/irq.h: In function `void enable_irqs(...)':
/brickos/include/lnp/sys/irq.h:104: parse error before `::'
make: *** [rcx1.o] Error 1
```

What can I do?

Comment: Is there some reason you are adding formatting characters to your inline assembly?  Once it gets compiled your `\t` and `\n` characters are kind of irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know, this is provided by brickOS developer...

Comment: I'm not sure what "cc" does on your platform, but if it doesn't do anything, you can simply remove the `:::"cc"` portion since you are not using the optional parameters anyway.

Comment: @ZacHowland: If you ask the compiler to produce assembly, then the contents of assembly blocks end up in the output verbatim (after operand substitution). Formatting characters can improve that output (although they clearly don't improve the source).

Comment: @MikeSeymour If I understand you correct, the brickOS developer spits out text-based assembly with formatting characters included?

Comment: @ZacHowland: That's certainly my experience with GCC in general. The compiler doesn't interpret or modify the assembly string beyond replacing the operands with the values it calculates from the constraints.

Comment: Thanks for all your reply. I decided to give up that source.

Answer (score 7):

GCC parses the characters sequence `:::` as *two* operators: The scope operator `::` and a colon `:`. It's because it matches the longest sequence it can when parsing keywords and operators. If you don't want that you need to add a space between each colon, like `: : :`